# Android STT backend

Tags: java, android, service, background

how do I create a speech to text engine that is constantly running in the background, and when something specific is said it loads the UI of the app? all of this is in java for android

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63804647/295004)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service or an async task to be executed continuously in background and update the UI when needed.

[Services](https://medium.com/@anitaa_1990/how-to-update-an-activity-from-background-service-or-a-broadcastreceiver-6dabdb5cef74)

[Async Task](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android-asynctask-example-and-explanation)

Comment: It worked when i tried to create a notification, but once i tried to use a STT it didn't work.